# Omni Channel Queue Based Routing - Chat Button

Tags: liveagent, queue, omnichannel

I want to understand how the following scenario works with Chat Transcript and Omni Channel.

I have a Routing Configuration, with multiple Queues - all related to the same Chat object.
Which of the following two actually happens, when a chat is initiated via a chat button?

1. When a chat is initiated, does it get assigned to the Queue associated with that chat button, and from there if the Queue is associated with a Routing Configuration it takes care of the assignment to the Agent as per the Routing Model?
2. Does the chat first get queued up at the Routing Configuration, and then it's assigned to a queue/agent as per their availability and the Routing model defined in the routing configuration?

I am thinking it's the 1st one - but I want to confirm how this works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assessment is most accurate. Each chat button with "Omni-Channel" routing types can be associated with at most 1 queue, which is the queue that the AgentWork record will end up in. The routing configuration specifies a capacity and routing model (and optionally, skills) for each queue it is associated with.

This allows you to set routing behaviors and capacities for many queues from a single configuration and defines what order those items make it to agents through the routing priority.

Chats don't get "queued up" at a routing configuration since the routing configuration itself is not a queue.

Comment: Thankyou so much @EvanSteeleSFDC.
Yeah, the chat's not getting queued up at Routing Configuration makes sense. Thankyou for clearing this for me.